# How to test shared code in Xamarin

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin

I have a Xamarin solution with 3 projects:

- Android
- iOS
- Shared

Shared is a shared project containing all the shared logic. E.g. database access using sqlite-net, rest calls using restsharp.

I want to test the code in Shared.

I created an NUnit Library Project and created a test in it.

Now the project cannot compile because it can't find dll's that the Shared project needs.

These dll's are not referenced directly by Shared. E.g., the Android project references the android version of the sqlitenet.dll.

How can I test the shared code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shared project is just a container for linked files, or put another way the shared project does not directly have any references but get whatever references the projects that reference it have.

If you have an iOS and Android project that reference a shared project, to properly unit test all possible code paths you would need android and iOS versions of the unit testing projects that reference the shared project and also reference anything the shared project needs, such as SqLite and define any needed compilation constants.

If the code is partially the same between the iOS and Android unit tests (and it likely is) you can use a shared project to share that code too.

Comment: So the shared tests project should be a "plain" shared project, right? And the ios and android test projects each use a different test library. Will I be able to use nunit (attributes) and moq in the shared tests?

Comment: Yes, a shared project is simply a container for linked files. It isn't a compiled entity in and of itself and all the files within it are compiled into whatever references the shared project. You would have to reference the correct unit testing library; nunitLite is available.

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit/ Also mocking may be a bit difficult for iOS as JIT that is required for frameworks like Moq are not available on physical iOS devices.

Comment: I can't seem to reference classes in the shared project from the shared-tests projects. Both projects are shared projects. I created an android test project and added references to the shared and shared tests projects. When I try to use classes from shared in shared-tests, Xamarin offers to make shared-tests reference the android (not android-tests) project.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. A shared project dies not contain any references. If you fully qualify the namespace when adding calls to the shared projects, does it work? Could you take a screen shot of the test project's references?

Comment: I got through that but I encounter another problem. I edited my question with the new problem.